# MouseEvent disabling

Tags: java, mouseevent

I am trying to create a Mouse Listener, and it works for the first few seconds and then it stops. Does anyone see a reason why it would stop? There are no other classes messing with MouseEvents or my display class other than when I get the BufferStrategy.

```
public void run() {
    init();

    int fps = 60;
    double timePerTick = 1000000000 / fps;
    double delta = 0;
    long now;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timer = 0;
    int ticks = 0;

    while(running){
        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerTick;
        timer += now - lastTime;
        lastTime = now;

        if(delta >= 1){
            tick();
            render();
            ticks++;
            delta--;
        }

        if(timer >= 1000000000){
            ticks = 0;
            timer = 0;
        }
    }

    stop();
}

private void init() {
        display = new Display(title, width, height);
        display.getFrame().addMouseListener(mouse);

        Assets.init();

        handler = new Handler(this);
}
```

Here is the listener

```
public class Mouse extends MouseAdapter{

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    System.out.println("2");
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("2");

}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("2");

}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("2");

}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("2");

}

}
```

Comment: There is no code for your mouse listener. How are supposed to figure what it is doing; if you are not showing all the code in use?

Comment: I am sorry I thought I put it in there

Comment: Could it be that "render()" isnt called any more after some time? And that prevents your UI from responding to anything?

Comment: @GhostCat I don't think so as everything is still rendering properly

Comment: I share GhostCat's opinion. A thread gets stuck in your while loop so the mouse events can't be handled or something similar might be happening.

Comment: @TheGamerPlayz Well, then I guess you should turn to the help center and read about creating minimal, viable example code that allows us to repro your problem. With the information/code that you provided so far, sorry, we cant help.

Comment: I gave you the all the code that has anything to do with rendering. When I removed everything that renders anything from an external class the mouse didn't even work for a second.